# PHP accessing String vars as Array and changing value

Tags: php

Is it ok to do this please?

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++)
{
    if(!in_array($str[$i],$arAllowedCharset)){$str[$i]='';}
}
return $str;
```

It works, but I am unsure if I am "allowed" to do that, i.e. `$str[$i]='';`.
Note: `$str` is a string variable, `$arAllowedCharset` is an array containing only alphanumerical characters and a dash.

I use that to format user-submitted URLs in a custom CMS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier to check and correct the url with a regular expression. For example

```
$str = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9-]#i', '', $str);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I wasn't sure if it was worth firing up the RegExp engine just for this.